# How to automatically update `tk.Label` when the value of `tk.Scale` changes?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I put in my frame scale, but I'm not sure how I can show the value of this scale in my label. I need to update it every time the scale moves. How can I do that?

```
self.options_settings.framepripojeni6 = Frame(self.options_settings.tab1)
        self.options_settings.framepripojeni6.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, expand=0, fill=tkinter.BOTH, padx=2, pady=4)

        self.options_settings.scale = Scale(self.options_settings.framepripojeni6,from_=1, to=60, length=350)
        self.options_settings.scale.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)

        self.options_settings.labelScale = tkinter.Label(self.options_settings.framepripojeni5, text="x")
        self.options_settings.labelScale.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the scale and label share a common variable, the label will automatically update. You can call the `set` method of the variable to provide a default value of the scale.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

scalevar = tk.IntVar()
scalevar.set(50)

scale = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, 
                 variable=scalevar, orient="horizontal")
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=scalevar)

scale.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
label.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes this working, thank you, in python 3.4 i must use tkinter with small T